# Why is my name featured in Top Users of the python tag?

Tags: support, top-users

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have a lot less reputation than other users in the list, and I also have far fewer badges. Then why is my name featured in All Time Top [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) Answerers? Is it a bug or an "encouragement thing" done by Stack Overflow?

Comment: I think it's just to show you where you are in comparison. I can't speak for the underlaying motivations. It's slightly confusing though, not really the best design.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. So the the number on extreme left, shows the points I earned in that respective tag (here its python) ? Okay, they could show it in a separate column, its confusing and disappointing to know that I still have a long way to go... ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Zoe says in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388824/why-is-my-name-featured-in-top-users-of-python-tag#comment723913_388824) it's to show you where you are in relation to the top users.

The first time I saw this I was confused, but when I realised what was going on it became clear.

I think that it would be clearer if there was a little bit more of a gap between the list proper and your entry.

Comment: Aren't we all top users?

Comment: If you checkout the page while logged out, you will notice that.